# Stop animation when view1 frame touch view2 frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

**My Code is as below.**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f animations:^{
        _view1.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x - 50,self.view.center.y - 50, 100, 100);
        _view2.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x - 50,self.view.center.y - 50, 100, 100);<br>
    } 
completion:nil];
```

Comment: You can stop animation using [view.layer removeAllAnimations];

Comment: I don't want to stop animation on completion, I want to stop animation when both view's frame touch each other.

Comment: Then change frame of _view2.frame accordingly.  why you are not doing so

Comment: Dear, Cause I want to do like this. I need to stop animation and perform some actions on views frame touch.

Comment: I this for a game? Then you should take a look at SpriteKit which has a collision detection.

Comment: Its not game, Its just animation on view. can you help me @clemens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collision detection of the frames of to views is a hard job in UIKit and I would solve it on the layer level, because animations take place on this level and the [presentation layer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410744-presentationlayer?language=objc) contains the current frame during an animation. So you have to observe the position and the bounds of the presentation layer**s** during the animation.

But observe is misleading here. You can't use KVO because Core Animation creates a new presentation layer for each animation step.